# If you're not going to review and fix questions, don't use the review queue!

Tags: discussion, review

I was sort of happy when I saw that the day after release we had 0 incoming new questions in the review queue! Aww man, nothing for me to do, everyone's taken care of all the incoming questions! Then I investigated by just manually reviewing the [12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.10) tag.

Many are missing any kind of information to help the poster make the questions better, and to my even greater shock, people are letting this junk through! With amazing titles like:

- "12.04 12.10 dist upgrade & xkill" <-- that is not even a sentence!
- "Workspace Switcher"

and so on. If everyone is reviewing new people's posts, how are they continuing to be so bad?

If you're not going to take the time to review them properly then please *don't use the review queue*, leave them in there for people who want to review! I now have to spend the rest of the day digging through the tag by hand. :(

Answer (score 23):

Looks like the review queue now has a rate limit of 20 per day. \o/

[image]

However now the review queue is empty so I have nothing to review. Since no one is taking this seriously I'm just going to point out horrible reviews here that people could have fixed if they weren't just clicking the OK button:

- [Ubuntu 12.10 Unity removing](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/60846) - not even a sentence, reviewed with no changes.
- [Authentication Failure Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/60821) - not even a sentence, reviewed with no changes.
- [keyboard ps2 on lenovo ideapad (atom, 2gb ram) doesn't work with 12.4 and 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/60801) - not a sentence, reviewed with clear errors in both the title and the body.
- [sip liphone issue](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/60693) - this is the perfect example of the garbage that people are letting through the review queue. This one even had an upvote!
- [macros…playonlinux](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/60572) - you read that correctly, the question is "macros...playonlinux." Accepted through review with *ZERO* edits. Also received an upvote!
- [Unable to correct problems](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/60068) - you and me both! Horrible title, sailed through review with no problems.
- [Device ID Missing [Solved]](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/59935) - at least the OP deleted this one, because the reviewer just let [SOLVED] right on through!
- [local-repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230989/local-repository) - what?

And I'm not even going to bother listing all the "wireless doesn't work" people are letting through, the obvious duplicates, and obvious bug reports.

So, if you're not going to use the queue right, please don't use it as it gives people who want to do a good job nothing to do when the queue is empty!

Comment: And to think I felt slightly bad for skipping a question because after 5 minutes agonising over it, I couldn't decide if it was a good question or not!