# What causes questions to drop into the 'review for deletion' queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

After reading [Jorge's post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5275/if-youre-not-going-to-review-and-fix-questions-dont-use-the-review-queue?cb=1) on using the review queue correctly I had a look at some of the questions and saw that [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228250/macros-playonlinux) had received one close vote and nothing else.

After adding a close vote (it's off topic, not 'too localised' IMO) I realised that I hadn't seen it in the queue for closure review.  Thinking that it would need to be flagged I added that too but I'm not sure this is correct.  Shouldn't one close vote have caused it to go to the queue for review?  Is something broken, or am I not understanding how it is supposed to work?

Comment: It is not offtopic, But it appears to be too localised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a race, but it's working as intended.

The post was enqueued, but was dealt with before anyone saw and acted on it in the close vote queue.  This was probably because of the flag.

In this case, almost immediately after it first entered the queue, the final close vote was cast by a moderator ([fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom)).  Since closed posts are immediately evicted from the close queue, it wasn't possible to see it anymore.

Additionally, since you had cast a close vote already we would never show you the post in the queue (since you couldn't act on it).