# Close Vote review queue 40 or 20?

Tags: discussion, close-review-queue

I've seen this question

[Why is there a 20 posts limit on the review queues?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7150/107450)

Recently however on some days I have been able to review 40 Close votes and on other days 20.  Is this a bug or by design? If it's by design what decides how many questions I can review in any one day.

I'm guessing that it's the length of the review queue allowing more reviews if the queue is above a certain size.

Also given that the Close review queue should we be reducing the number of votes required to either close a question or keep it open (removing from the queue)?

Alternatively should people be able review more questions or encouraging more people to review?

I'm not suggesting the limits should be removed entirely we don't want to burn anybody out, or have only a small number of people effectively defining the "house style" for the entire site.

But, I do think we should eventually be able clear each of the review queues every day. At the moment it looks like the Close review queue will never be cleared.  I'm thinking more along the lines that we should on average be able between us be able to reduce the total size of the queue by say 50 a day so we eventually get to the point where bad questions and answers get removed quickly.

Once the backlog has been cleared the maximum amount of reviews we all have should of course be reduced again.

Comment: Considering there are nearly 1k questions most of the time at the moment in the Close vote review queue, if people want to review 20+ questions it is likely a good idea to let them - (I can barely get past 5...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The close queue is dynamic**. If all the pending task are over 1,000 the amount of alloted reviews for each user rise to 40. Once the queue is below 1,000 the queue returns to the original 20.

Reference:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223917/213575

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can and should maybe drop the trigger point a bit so so we can reduce some of the backlog?

Comment: @WarrenHill that you should ask in another meta-Q.

Comment: - Done question here: [http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11507/107450](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11510/107450)