# Should we be able to review 40 close votes when the queue length is less than 1000?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-review-queue

I recently asked this question on Meta

[Close Vote review queue 40 or 20?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11507/107450)

Regarding why on some days I have been able to review 40 close reviews but on others only 20  and received the answer that the queue was dynamic and that if the length of the review queue was more than 1000 the number of reviews we are each allowed is increased to 40.

Is this threshold something that can be changed and if it is can and should we be reducing the threshold to a level where we can gradually reduce the queue to the point where we can eventually reach the point where on average we can between us clear the Close review queue each day.

I would not be in favour of allowing more than 40 votes as to properly review questions takes time and effort.  We certainly don't want people to review on auto-pilot blindly closing everything or leaving everything open.  Nor do I want to burn people out.

However, at the moment the close queue is too long and bad questions and answers are taking too long to be closed

Comment: @Wilf - I don't think we should overload people with too many reviews but making it 40 reviews when the queue was longer than something less than 1000 would enable us to reduce the backlog.

Comment: I understand the point, just not the title  :-) (I'm getting mixed with the 'dropping' etc, when we need to increase the limit to allow for more reviews to reduce the backlog...)

Comment: The math indicates that at the current settings (40@1000, 20<1000) that it would take 25 users to clear the queue if the 40 close reviews stayed static at that level when there were 1000 awaiting review, but when it drops to <1000 (999?) it would take 50 users doing their fair share to get the job done. It seems rather odd to double the required staffing when headway is being made....

Comment: I do now very much agree with this - I just did my first full 20 amount of reviews in the Close queue *(yes I sort of haven't gone near the close vote queue previously)*... I probably could do a few more.

Comment: The [user reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/year/askubuntu/2014-01-01?sort=totalreputation) indicate that there are currently 279 people with 3k+ reputation. If 20% of them get involved this becomes a non-issue. Is there a way to rally/motivate them?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a user set a preferred level?

Comment: The post title is mathematically wrong. It looks like your are asking for 40 close votes when reviews<1k and 20 votes when reviews>1k.

Comment: @RegisteredUser feel free to edit the title to something better.  It was originally about reducing the threshold.  But just because its asking if we should have 40 votes when reviews < 1000, does not imply less votes when > 1000.

Comment: Since nobody has been able to answer this question yet. I have asked this question [Close Vote review thresholds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236618/215577) on Meta StackExchange to find out if what I'm asking is even technically possible or if the limits are hard coded and thus unchangeable.

Comment: @WarrenHill is there any progress on an answer?

Comment: @WildMan - Not as yet I've put a small bounty on the question and as I write there are 7 up votes but as yet no answers.  If anyone here has reputation to spare on Meta StackExchange you may want to increase the size of the bounty or up vote it to give it more prominence.