# How to deal with higher quality duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, question-quality, answer-quality

Occasionally on a stack exchange, one will have a very precise question cited as a duplicate to a very broad question, or one will have a very clear and straight to the point question cited as a duplicate to a long winded question full of irrelevance. I assume this happens to everyone to some level. I personally can find it very alienating, and off putting when it happens to me, especially if the duplicate does not have very good answers.

In the Ubuntu Stack Exchange, what should be the policy be in accordance to this situation?

Comment: Get advice. Flag it or ask in [chat]. If people agree that the new question is not a duplicate or is of much better quality than the first question (the one asked earlier) we can reopen it or even reverse the duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a concept all users needs to be very clear of, and they usually get them wrong:

```
Question A        Question B
Requeriment 1     Requeriment 1
Requeriment 2
Requeriment 3
Requeriment 4
Requeriment 5
Requeriment 6
```

A is a subset of B, yes; they are related, yes; some of the answers of B can apply to A, yes; but ultimately they are not duplicates. A is a duplicate of B **if every reasonable answer** to B also reasonably answers A. If you have an answer that applies to B but not to A, or otherwise, you are most surely not dealing with a duplicated.

If you have been victim of this behavior, drop in chat  (feel free to ping me, I love defend those cases) or flag and explain your case.

I, myself, have been affected by this with some questions here on AU and SO, and I've proved that my question is unique enough; most of the cases I defend, suffer of this. Even one that I identified as duplicated, were proved wrong by someone that dropped a comment saying that my case was actually special in UL.