# Why are we marking these UEFI questions as duplicates of the wrong question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, closed-questions, canonical-questions

I see many, many questions written by users having trouble installing Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration on their UEFI-enabled PC, that are being marked as duplicates of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). This would appear to be a problem, because this "canonical question" is actually about installing Wubi-style, not true dual-boot, which is a whole other thing entirely. The user cannot possibly glean anything useful from the question they are directed to.

Here are a few examples:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/455503/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-problem-uefi?rq=1
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/516981/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-1-in-dual-boot-with-windows-8-in-notebook-asus-r103b
- [Install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291206/install-ubuntu-13-04-alongside-windows-8)

Comment: True, they are actually pointed there for the answer. I have commented on it so minerz can change it.

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken recorder but it's [because people don't read fully the questions](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11595/169736) and prefer just to lazily mark as duplicates.

Comment: Richard, @Braiam: Even before the latest edit, the question did not specify using Wubi as *goal*, only that it's what the OP *had tried.* Are you actually saying none of the *answers* to [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) explain how to install Ubuntu with its own partitions (i.e., non-Wubi)? Is [Luis's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/22949) not a guide to doing exactly that? My impression is that dupes to that question have been helping many people dual boot Windows 8 and (non-Wubi) Ubuntu.

Comment: To quote Luis' answer: `So with all of this said, installing Ubuntu via WUBI is not doable (not recommended at least from me), things like trying to boot for example with the Windows 8 bootloader are not possible right now unless something changes in the future (There are also some bugs related to this in launchpad, like the one mentioned by bcbc).` That's the 3rd paragraph. To quote the second bullet in the directions: `You are not installing Ubuntu inside of Windows 8 but rather alongside of it. Inside of it is impossible because it needs Wubi which is unsupported`.

Comment: @Seth the title is misleading then.

Comment: @Braiam It makes perfect sense to me, and I've never heard anyone misunderstand it until now.

Comment: The confusing thing was that the question asker was trying to use Wubi to accomplish his/her goal.